# SlickGrid spreadsheet. How to make?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am interested in [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) plugin. I saw that there is a spreadsheet example, but it doesn`t work. Is it really possible to make a spreadsheet with selecting range of cells and copy paste selected cells? Maybe somewhere I can find an example?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" there?

Comment: Is it possible to configure to copy/paste from/to Excel ?

Comment: I noticed a missing script reference and fixed it.  There is no built-in support for copy/paste from Excel, but you can implement it.

Comment: Excel's copy/paste is really simple - it looks like CSV but the delimiter is \t (TAB - 09 in ascii table). So implementing it shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CellExternalCopyManager plugin : http://labs.nereo.fr/slick.html

Comment: I know this one. Try it before you list it. It doesn't work at all in Google-Chrome. It worked for exactly one time in InternetExplorer 9. When you copy something into the clipboard, and try to copy again, it doesn't work anywhere anymore. It is unreliable and not cross-browser. It also includes the files with wrong case-sensitivity. 
Definitely not a solution, and has definitely not been tested cross-platform.
Yet they claim it is cross-browser and cross-platform, when it actually is neither.

Comment: It works with Chrome and IE9 but slickgrid must have the focus. Please be sure that Slickgrid has the focus or handle key events from window and send them to the slickgrid plugin.

If you experiment problems please fill free to report the issue : https://github.com/Celebio/SlickGrid/issues

Comment: @Quandary I made some bug fixes, could you please test it again with the last commit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great resource detailing many open source web based Spreadsheets

http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/01/30/javascript-grid-editor-i-want-to-be-excel/

Comment: My question was specifically about SlickGrid. I don't want another spreadsheet. I already have one that works but is too slow. Only SlickGrid delivers the necessary performance.